# Writing canonical question for finding living descendants of person?

Tags: discussion, canonical

The question that prompted this: [Finding descendants of Jamaican immigrant to England](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/q/15581/1006)

We have several "I want to find the descendants of [name]" questions on the site, some of which have been closed as duplicates of this question. [Finding descendants of British great grand uncle who emigrated to Australia?](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/q/8151/1006)

The techniques for finding descendants may be the same for all localities, but the resources for each locality will differ. (Related question: [Is the same question in a different geographical area a duplicate?](https://genealogy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2046/1006))

I thought we had addressed this already with one good question on doing descendancy research, but I wasn't able to find it.  I think we need a better Q/A as our model for closing Qs as duplicates instead of the one that just happened to be posted first.

To that end, I'm going to answer here with some links to resources to show what kinds of things I would include in a self-answered canonical question.

Your thoughts?

Note: We already have [Contacting living distant relatives?](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/q/255/1006) on Contacting Living Relatives so the resources which address how to make contact belong in an answer over there.

Answer (score 3):

Many of the print articles I'm finding are too specific to FamilySearch's Family Tree or to doing temple work. The ones about the etiquette of contacting living relatives probably belong as an answer on our existing question.

Further reading:

- Genealogy Today: [How to Contact Living Relatives](https://www.genealogytoday.com/articles/reader.mv?ID=2676) by Gena Philibert-Ortega
- Podcast Episode notes: [Why Your DNA Matches Aren’t Responding](https://www.amyjohnsoncrow.com/ancestrydna-matches-arent-responding/) by Amy Johnson Crow
- [14 Steps For Contacting Kin](https://lisalouisecooke.com/2017/08/09/contact-distant-relatives/) by Lisa Louise Cooke, from *Genealogy Gems*
- FamilySearch Research Wiki: [Finding Living Relatives (National Institute)](https://www.familysearch.org/wiki/en/Finding_Living_Relatives_(National_Institute)) is US-centric

Videos:

- Crista Cowan's "Barefoot Genealogist" video: [Descendancy Research](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_q7yAh8Anok)
- FamilySearch Lesson, Tim Bingaman, AG®: [Descendancy Research](https://www.familysearch.org/ask/learningViewer/998)
- RootsTech presentation:Michael L.Strauss: [Descendancy Research: Another Pathway to Genealogy](https://www.rootstech.org/video/descendancy-research-another-pathway-to-genealogy)
- Diahan Southard: [DNA: The Glue that Holds Families Together](https://www.rootstech.org/videos/diahan-southard) (contains advice on contacting DNA matches)